# My activities opacity is lowering itself on older version of android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently writing a program and on only one of my activities all the icons on the screen are lowering their opacity to almost see-through.

This only happens on Android 5.0 and lower. I tested this with an emulator and everything above Android 5.0 are perfectly fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clockinoutbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#357780">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clockInOutImgView"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/clockinorouttext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chimetimewhite" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/clockinorouttext"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#357780"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="CLOCK WORKER IN/ OUT"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/personnellogbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#1E3059">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/personnellogimgview"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/personnellogtext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/personnellogwhite" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personnellogtext"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#1E3059"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="PERSONNEL LOG"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addnewworkerbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#357780">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addworkerimgview"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/addworkertext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/addnewworkerwhite" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addworkertext"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#357780"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="ADD NEW OPERATIVE"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timesheetsbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#1E3059">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/timesheetsimgview"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/timesheettext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/timesheetswhite" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/timesheettext"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#1E3059"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="TIMESHEETS"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Some screenshots would be apreciated

Comment: @litelite Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/cHmYGQB

Comment: Thats the difference between android 5.0 and android 5.1